# Executing an external program with parameters

Tags: python, subprocess

I searched for this, but most answers are for more complicated solutions and I'm new at this. I am doing a project where I have a C program.  I need to call it from a python script that I am writing.  The C program will ask for an input of a single letter (n for name, q for quit).  In my program I want to send n for name.  Then send my name. Then exit.  The C program will print my name, then exit.

I don't need to get the output.  Just send the text.  I've been experimenting with subprocess, and have this written, but keep getting stuck:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(["./askforname"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
p.communicate(input='n')
```

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the programming language with which the program was written, so I don't see the need for a c tag

Comment: you should look into using the `pexpect` module ... it is fairly complicated to do this with just Popen and pipes

Comment: I played around with pexpect a bit, it looked like it should work, but got stuck on that too--any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: as an aside, paramaters are passed in through the command line ... this is program input ... it would be much easier if you could change the input to be command line parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
p = Popen(["./askforname"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
time.sleep(1) # sleep long enough for program to have prompted for single letter
p.stdin.write("n\n") #n with a newline
time.sleep(1) # sleep long enough for program to have prompted for name
p.stdin.write("my name\n") # dont forget the newline
time.sleep(1) # sleep long enough the program goes back to asking for single letter
p.stdin.write("q\n") # now send quit

print p.communicate()
```

may work ... but it is probably better to use something like pexpect so you can wait for expected prompts until they appear rather than for a specific time and hope they are there waiting

Comment: I think this works, however the print p.communicate() line actually prints out the c code prompts in a single line.  Instead of asking for name then printing a new line, the c code shows : menu \n, q, exit\n  etc.  So I'm not positive it's working.

Comment: that means its working since the program wouldnt print the next prompt unless it got an answer